# select distinct with constant value for left join mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a table `t_tender_cpv_details` where there is a field `tender_id`. There are 3 rows with value 2.

I need to left join the table with itself. It has some constant values as well. The right side is not returning any value. Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
SELECT  a.tender_id,b.const_field FROM (SELECT tender_id FROM t_tender_cpv_details WHERE tender_id=2 ) a
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT 'A' AS const_field, tender_id  FROM t_tender_cpv_details WHERE 1=2 ) b ON (a.tender_id=b.tender_id)
```

Result:

```
 tender_id  const_field
 2,(NULL)
 2,(NULL)
 2,(NULL)
```

Now, for MySQL 5.7, when we add a `distinct` to the clause, the `const_field` field automatically adds the constant value.
Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.tender_id,b.const_field FROM (SELECT tender_id FROM t_tender_cpv_details WHERE tender_id=2 ) a
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT 'A' AS const_field, tender_id  FROM t_tender_cpv_details WHERE 1=2 ) b ON 
(a.tender_id=b.tender_id)
```

Result:

```
tender_id  const_field
2,A
```

In MySQL 5.5, we got the proper result which is 2, (NULL). Upgrading MySQL version to 5.7 is throwing this error.

Please help me resolve this Issue.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is this correct `WHERE 1=2` ? 1 will never be equal to 2...

Comment: @Mureinik no error message, but an unexpected result - the second query should not return 'A' for const_field, as the join should never succeed

Comment: Is it logically correct to include+run code which will never succeed?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw, that is specifically my point... The result is unexpected in MySQL 5.7 when added distinct.

Comment: Have you checked what result you get with just the subquery _"SELECT 'A' AS const_field, tender_id  FROM t_tender_cpv_details WHERE 1=2"_

Comment: @Spidey If you're trying to reduce a problem to a minimum verifiable example to demonstrate a bug, it is.

Comment: Does anybody have any update on this? We are kind of stuck with the version upgrade and need urgent fixing. Can this be a bug in MySQL 5.7? Is there any way around to this Issue?

Comment: We raised the bug to MySQL and got the below work around:Work-around is to turn off optimizer_switch derived_merge:

mysql> set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'; This is working fine but my point is that any optimization should not break basic sql properties.